# Pointer sets to null-pointer when going out of function

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, null

I have quite a blocking problem which I don't understand. Generally, I'm making a kind of anthill simulation. There is one main passage inside divided into segments and from some of the segments ants can enter into chambers. All of these three classes (Passage, Segment, Chamber) have one common thing - collection of ants currently visiting them. So there is an abstract class `AntHolder`, which contains `vector<Ant*>` (only members relevant to the case are shown):

```
    class AntHolder
    {
    protected:
        std::vector<Ant*> ants;
        /* some other members here */

    public:          
        virtual bool antEnter(Ant* ant) = 0;
        /* some other functions here */
    };
```

The `antEnter` function is implemented differently in derived classes, but generally serves the purpose of adding ant to the `ants`. From the derived classes particularly I'm interested in `AntChamber` class (here also less important members were omitted):

```
    class AntChamber : public AntHolder
    {
    protected:
        int itemCapacity;
        int additionalCapacity;
        std::vector<Item*> items;

        bool hasFood;
        bool hasEgg;

    public:
        bool putItem(Item* item);
        virtual bool antEnter(Ant* ant);
    };
```

The `putItem` function is similar to the `antEnter` function, but it adds `Item` objects to `items` collection. (Items are e.g. food, which are moved by ants from one chamber to another.) Below there is shown implementation of both functions:

```
    bool AntChamber::antEnter(Ant* ant)
    {
        if (items.size() + ants.size() == itemCapacity + additionalCapacity) return false;

        ants.push_back(ant);
        return true;
    }

    bool AntChamber::putItem(Item* item)
    {
        if (items.size() == itemCapacity ||
            items.size() + ants.size() == itemCapacity + additionalCapacity)
            return false;

        if (item->getItemKind() == Food) hasFood = true; // Food == enum value
        else if (item->getItemKind() == Egg) hasEgg = true; // Egg == enum value

        items.push_back(item);
        return true;
    }
```

You can clearly see, that they're almost identical. But when it comes to their effect, there is crucial, surprising difference, and that is the core of my problem.

Let's say I already have an `AntChamber* chamber` constructed. When I run the following piece of code:

```
    Item* item = new Item(Food);
    chamber->putItem(item);
```

, then after that both `item` and `chamber->items.back()` points to some memory with this object. But when I run the analogous piece of code:

```
    Ant* ant = new Ant(chamber);
    chamber->antEnter(ant));
```

, then after that `ant` point to the object, but `chamber->ants.back()` points to NULL!

I absolutely can't understand what is going on, especially, that both `putItem` and `antEnter` in fact do the same thing: `push_back` the pointer, which was passed by parameter. I have already tried to simulate such case in some simplier code, like:

```
    class A { };
    class B { };

    class C
    {
        vector<A*> va;
        vector<B*> vb;
    public:
        A* vaBack() { return va.back(); }
        B* vbBack() { return vb.back(); }

        void addA(A* a) { va.push_back(a); }        
        void addB(B* b) { vb.push_back(b); }
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        A* a = new A();
        B* b = new B();
        C* c = new C();

        cout << (unsigned int)a << endl;
        c->addA(a);
        cout << (unsigned int)c->vaBack() << endl;

        cout << (unsigned int)b << endl;
        c->addB(b);
        cout << (unsigned int)c->vbBack() << endl;

        delete c;
        delete b;
        delete a;
    }
```

, but it appears to work just fine - none of pointers is 0x000000.

Comment: Did you check the return value of `chamber->antEnter(ant));` was not `false`? Since we do not have a Short, self contained example it is hard to pin down the problem: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: In antEnter, what are the values of itemCapacity and additionalCapacity? And did you really want to use itemCapacity in antEnter?

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour - I did. It's not the case. When I test it, both vectors are empty, ant both capacities are way higher - e.g. 10 + 5. As you see, I tried to simplify example, but my attempt has failed :)

Comment: @Sushi271 Ok, can you reduce your code to an SSCCE that reproduces the problem? It seems like the issue is in the part of the code we do not have.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer - it's quite irrelevant to the case I think; but if you ask: the idea is, that you can fill chamber with items up to an itemCapacity limit, but some space must be left for ants, so they could come in. But if there is lesser items, than itemCapacity, then more ants can come in. So itemCapacity + additionalCapacity = totalCapacity, which can't be exceed by both ants and items. But ants have no other limits themselves, unlike items.

Comment: Step through `AntChamber::antEnter` with a debugger, examining every object of interest at every step.

Comment: @n.m. unfortunately, for reasons I won't say here,  I'm bound to coding in gedit/vim/emacs, and compiling by g++ from shell.

Comment: Unfortunately? That's at least debatable. You now have an opportunity to learn either gdb, or the art of printf debugging.

Comment: I already have some printf debugging in my experience. Pain in ass...

Answer (score 1):

Oh My God, I'm sooo blind...

I did SSCCE, as **Shafik Yaghmour** advised and I noticed the problem while doing it.

I used a mental leap, saying, that `chamber->items.back()` or `chamber->ants.back()` are NULL, because in fact, they weren't! But they're protected in their classes, so I wrote in both classes a function to get to i-th item/ant. The problem was this function. It made a standard idiotproof protection against giving index out of vector's bonds, but made a mistake doing so:

```
    if (idx < 0 || ants.size() >= idx) return 0; // SHOULD BE <= !!!
    return ants[idx];
```

so it always returned 0... And I looked at this method maybe hundreds of times when looking for this problem, and never noticed anything wrong (till now).

Stupid mistake... Thank you very much **Shafik**.

Comment: That is one of the points of doing an SSCCE and I guessed you might figure it out on your own. In many cases trying to demonstrate the bug in a smaller example leads to figuring out the problem.